# JsTree dnd issue

Tags: javascript, jstree

I'm using JsTree and my goal is to have no child nodes, no hierarchy at all, just root nodes. I saw an old example [here](http://johntang.github.io/JsTree/_docs/dnd.html) (reorder only) for version **1.0rc3** and works fine but I need the same functionality in version **3.0.2** which doesn't include crrm plugin.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

config for v1.0rc3

```
{ 
        "crrm" : { 
            "move" : {
                "check_move" : function (m) { 
                    var p = this._get_parent(m.o);
                    if(!p) return false;
                    p = p == -1 ? this.get_container() : p;
                    if(p === m.np) return true;
                    if(p[0] && m.np[0] && p[0] === m.np[0]) return true;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        },
        "dnd" : {
            "drop_target" : false,
            "drag_target" : false
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "html_data", "crrm", "dnd" ]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```
                "core": {
                    "check_callback": true,
                    'data': [...]
                },
                "types": {
                    "default":{
                        "max_depth": 0,
                    },

                },
                "plugins": ["dnd","types"]
```

Another fix, from the creator on [google forums](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jstree/JnoKhgA_g1M)

```
core : {
  check_callback : function (op, node, par, pos, more) {
    if((op === "move_node" || op === "copy_node") && node.parent !== par.id) { return false; }
    return true;
  }, ...
```